# Jenkins | DSL| Workspace DIR issue

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-job-dsl

I have a Jenkin DSL JOB. It's for java build. I am stuck in a strange problem.
jobname is DSL, I saw a workspace with the name of DSL is created, But when the job runs it added another workspace with the name of DSL@2. The problem I can not get final jar file from DSL workspace

```
pipeline 
{
    agent any
    stages 
    {
        stage('Build') 
        {

            agent   {
                docker { image 'maven:latest'

                    args  '-v /home/ubuntu/jenkins/jenkins_home/.m2:/root/.m2'

                       }
                    }
                        steps {
                            git branch: "${params.branch}", url: "git@github.org/repo.git"
                            sh 'mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true -Dfindbugs.skip=true'
                            sh "ls -la target/name.jar "

                             }


        }

        stage('Copy Artifects')
    { 
        steps {
           //print "$params.IP"
           // sh '${params.IP}"
       sh "ls -la && pwd "
     sh "scp target/name.jar ubuntu@${params.IP}:/home/ubuntu/target/name.jar_2"

             }
    }  
}
}
```

OUT Of the JOB

```
Compiling 19 source files to /var/jenkins_home/workspace/dsl@2/auth-client/target/classes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DSL@2 means you either have a concurrent job configured and two builds runnning at the same time, OR you got a bug https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-30231

To address your issue:
you are building *stage('Build')* inside a docker container created from maven image.
However, *stage('Copy Artifects')* is run OUTSIDE of that container

To fix it, you need to move *agent{}* to pipeline{} level like this:

```
pipeline 
{
    agent   {
                docker { 
                    image 'maven:latest'
                    args  '-v /home/ubuntu/jenkins/jenkins_home/.m2:/root/.m2'
                    }
            }
    stages 
    {
        stage('Build') 
        {
            steps {
                git branch: "${params.branch}", url: "git@github.org/repo.git"
                sh 'mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true -Dfindbugs.skip=true'
                sh "ls -la target/name.jar "
            }
        }

        stage('Copy Artifects')
        { 
            steps {

                sh "ls -la && pwd "
                sh "scp target/name.jar ubuntu@${params.IP}:/home/ubuntu/target/name.jar_2"
            }
        }  
    }
}
```